# Change property only once in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I `unbold` text in `ListBox` on selection and keep it this way after removing selection? In my code bold returns after removing selection.

I already tried to use `Mode = "OneTime"` but it works for one item only.

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding EmailsCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Sender}" Style="{StaticResource Sender}" Name="SenderLabel" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Subject}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Date}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    </Grid>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers >
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                                {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=
                                                {x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="SenderLabel" Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by having an "IsRead" property inside your Email ViewModel. Then, you can set the IsRead property to true whenever a new selection has occurred. The "IsRead" property will be used inside a trigger for the sender label to change it's font weight. See below.

xaml:

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding EmailsCollection}" Margin="5"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Sender}" x:Name="SenderLabel">
                        <Label.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Label">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRead}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Label.Style> 
                    </Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Subject}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Date}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Email> EmailsCollection { get; private set; }

    private Email _selectedItem;
    public Email SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            if (_selectedItem.IsRead) return;
            if (value != null)
            {
                EmailsCollection[EmailsCollection.IndexOf(value)].IsRead = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel() 
    {
        EmailsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Email>()
        {      
            new Email
            {
                Sender = "Sender",
                Subject = "Subject",
                Date = "Date"
            },
            new Email
            {
                Sender = "Sender1",
                Subject = "Subject1",
                Date = "Date1"
            },
            new Email
            {
                Sender = "Sender2",
                Subject = "Subject2",
                Date = "Date2"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Email ViewModel:

```
   public class Email : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool _isRead;
        public bool IsRead
        {
            get { return _isRead; }
            set
            {
                _isRead = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsRead");
            }
        }

        public string Sender { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in your view model instead, i.e. give your list items a property (e.g. "Highlight") and then in your SelectedItem setter have it set that value to true as items are selected. Then in your XAML set the style for the list items to set the text as bold when Highlight has been set.

XAML is very powerful and can do a lot of clever things but things you do with it can't be easily unit tested or debugged. Implement functionality like this explicitly in your view models and restrict your XAML to loosely-bound UI elements only.

Answer (score 0):

I would have in the item a property like "WasSelected" and bind the FontWeight of to that property using a converter.